# Common Refinement: What is it? Upper and Lower Sums: Darboux Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

See p. 3 of the following worksheet [here](https://sagrawalx.github.io/teaching/su15_math104/lec24_int.pdf) (specifically Corolarry 2.2).

In the corollary, it states that if $R$ is a common refinement of $P$ and $Q$ that $L(f, P) ≤ L(f, R) ≤ U(f, R) ≤ U(f, Q)$ looking at Lemma 2.1 above it.

How does this make even make sense? A common refinement is a refinement of both partitions "simultaneously." What does simultaneously mean? I would think that it would mean $R\supseteq P,Q$ implying $L(f, P) ≤ L(f, R) ≤ U(f, R) ≤ U(f, P)$ and $L(f, Q) ≤ L(f, R) ≤ U(f, R) ≤ U(f, Q)$ which doesn't prove the theorem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am starting to think it just means union too. Still, it doesn't make sense. https://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/lecture_notes/lecture15-16.pdf

Comment: Why doesn't it prove the theorem?  What you have shown is stronger than the theorem statement.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I didn't even see that lol. Thank you!